# How to use tensorflow model to train and predict mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

```
<html>
<body id='body'>
    <button onclick="StartData(event)"> Start</button>
    <button onclick="getStopCordinates(event)">Stop</button>
    <script>
        let inputs = [];
        let labels = [];
        function Mouse(event) {
            inputs.push({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY })
        }
        function StartData() {
            document.getElementById('body').addEventListener("mouseover", Mouse())
        }

        function getStopCordinates(event) {
            labels.push({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY })
            document.getElementById('body').removeEventListener("mouseover", Mouse())
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using above code to capture all the x y coordinates of the mouse in the body . When the user moves the pointer towards the stop button i am capturing all the x,y coordinates for this . and when user clicks stop i am capturing stop coordinates also . now i want to train the tensorflow js model from the captured points so that when user moves the mouse with same trajectory i can predict  that he will click the stop button .

tensorflow code :

```
 const model = tf.sequential(); 

  // Add a single hidden layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [2], units: 1, useBias: true}));

  // Add an output layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, useBias: true}));

  const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1]);
    const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labels, [labels.length, 1]);

trainModel(model,inputs,labels)
async function trainModel(model, inputs, labels) {
  // Prepare the model for training.  
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
    metrics: ['mse'],
  });

  const batchSize = 32;
  const epochs = 50;

  return await model.fit(inputs, labels, {
    batchSize,
    epochs,
    shuffle: true,
    callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
      { name: 'Training Performance' },
      ['loss', 'mse'], 
      { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
    )
  });
}
```

but this code gives error as the inputs and labels are not the same so how to correct this code for the above result ?

Comment: Without seeing the inputs and labels shape, I think that this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737522/tensorflow-js-inputshape-doesnt-match-model-input

Comment: @edkeveked Input is as following  input = [{x:1,y:2},{x:4,y:6}...] it goes further

Answer (score 0):

The inputs and labels should be an array of array and not an array of object. The inputs should rather be

```
 [[1, 2], [4, 6], ...]
```

The same thing holds for the labels.

Since your are predicting 2 values, the last layer should have as number of units 2

```
 const model = tf.sequential(); 

 // Add a single hidden layer
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [2], units: 1, useBias: true}));

 // Add an output layer
 model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, useBias: true}));
```

The last thing - surely not the least - is to add activation in order to add non linearity to the model